# DevTools cannot "add new style rule" for local webpages since upgrading to Chrome version 64

Tags: google-chrome

Reproduce the problem:

1. Create an any html file and launch it in Google Chrome. The URL will be like "file:///C:/test.htm" in the address bar.
2. Right click on the page --> Choose "Inspect"
3. Try to click the "Add new style rule" icon for any elements, it won't work. The newly added style rule will disappear on the panel when trying to edit it.
4. If using the URL of "http://localhost/test.htm" to open the webpage in Chrome, "Add new style rule" works perfectly. The issue has started exist since upgrading to Chrome 64. It used to work very well for this feature.
5. Tested in many other computers, all got the same problem.

[image: Screenshot of the problem]

Comment: i have the same problem, no solution, tried to reinstall chrome.. and its stays the same...

Comment: I have reported the issue to Chrome team, they can reproduce on their environment and will fix it in Chrome version 65 or 66. 

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=814937#c19

For a temporary solution, you can install Mongoose or other web servers, and use the URL like "localhost/yourweb.htm" to open your files in Chrome, then you can add styles without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

the only solution (for now) for fixing this issue is to install the previews version 63 of chrome and stop the chrome from auto update on windows 10

download chrome older version from here:
https://www.slimjet.com/chrome/google-chrome-old-version.php

and a guide to stop chrome from auto update in windows 10:
https://www.technobezz.com/disable-google-chrome-auto-update-in-windows-10/

also report this issue in the google chrome "about section" in settings.

waiting to the the next version to check if the issue is fixed...